# Linux pthread Producer and consumer problem in c - why does my code not print any output?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, mutex

I'm supposed to write a producer function that gets each character from a string, and then, using a shared buffer, the Consumer takes each of those characters that the producer gets and prints it out.

However, whenever I run my program nothing gets printed out.

I'm new to pthreads and sempahores, so I'm getting something wrong.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 2
#define PRODUCER_SIZE 2

//string
char message[] = "Now is the time for all good people to come to the aid of their country";
int msgindex = 0;

// our buffer
static char BUFFER[BUFFER_SIZE];
int size = (sizeof(message)/sizeof(message[0]))-1;

//out in and out positions
static int in;
static int out;

//semaphores declaration
sem_t manage_empty;
sem_t manage_full;
sem_t manage_cs;

//declaration of threads
pthread_t producers[PRODUCER_SIZE];
pthread_t consumer;

void* consumer_function(void* arg){

char c_buff;

sem_wait(&manage_full);
sem_wait(&manage_cs);
///////////CS//////////
while(out < in){

c_buff = BUFFER[out];
printf("%c\n",c_buff);
out++;
}
in = 0;
///////////END_CS//////
sem_post(&manage_cs);
sem_post(&manage_empty);

return NULL;
}//end consumer_function

void* producer_function(void* arg){

char p_buff;

sem_wait(&manage_empty);
sem_wait(&manage_cs);
/////////CS////////////
while(in < BUFFER_SIZE){
p_buff = message[msgindex];
BUFFER[in] = p_buff;
in++;
msgindex++;
}
out = 0;
////////END_CS/////////
sem_post(&manage_cs);
sem_post(&manage_full);

return NULL;
}//end producer_function

int main(){

//initialize semaphore
sem_init(&manage_empty, 0, 1);
sem_init(&manage_full, 0, 0);
sem_init(&manage_cs, 0, 1);

//initialize variable counters
in = 0;
out = 0;

//creation of threads
int x;
    for(x=0;x<PRODUCER_SIZE;x++){
        pthread_create(&producers[x],NULL,producer_function,NULL);
    }//end for loop

    pthread_create(&consumer,NULL,consumer_function,NULL);

    for(x=0;x<PRODUCER_SIZE;x++){
        pthread_join(producers[x],NULL);
    }//end for loop

    pthread_join(consumer,NULL);

    sem_destroy(&manage_empty); 
    sem_destroy(&manage_full); 
    sem_destroy(&manage_cs); 

return 1;
}//end main function
```

Comment: Your `main` function does not wait and exits immediately which will kill all the threads. Trying calling `pthread_join`.

Comment: Sorry, reading your code gives me a headache. Please fix up the indentation and also update with what you have changed.

Comment: @kaylum i added the join but it still print nothing out, can you check if i'm using semaphores correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You start only one consumer thread, and it prints *at most* one buffered character and one newline.  But it may print nothing at all, because it is possible for it to lock the mutex before any characters have been produced.

And *that*'s possible because you initialize all the semaphores to have value 1, whereas it appears that you would want to initialize `manage_full` with value 0, so that the consumer will wait until something is produced before trying to consume anything.

Even then, however, your producers run in one-shot mode, too. Each one will produce at most one character before it terminates.

Also, you have at least one too many synchronization objects.  Observe how no thread acquires mutex `lock` without first decrementing semaphore `manage_cs`, how that semaphore is initialized to have value 1, and how no thread posts to it without having previously decremented it.  That is a perfectly good way to use `manage_cs` as a mutex, and with that being the case, you don't need *another* mutex that is always and only locked when `manage_cs` is locked.

What's more, your producer double-increments variable `in`, with result that the first output character is written at index 1, not 0, in the buffer.  Also, it resets `in` to zero after producing two characters, but that doesn't make sense because it is use as the index of the next character to produce from the data.  Thus, if the consumer *does* print a character then it will definitely be the null character to which `BUFFER[0]` is initialized and not anything from the data string.

There may be other issues as well.

Comment: I updated the code, can you explain what you mean by my producers and consumers run in one shot mode?

Comment: @h2lawal: 1. Do not make meaningful modifications to your question after you have received answers.  2. One-shot mode: as it was presented at the time this answer was written, your producer threads each produced just one character before terminating, and your consumer consumed just one character before terminating.  Typically, producer and consumer would both loop, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your producers produce the entire string in a single loop, and the consumer consumes the entire string in a single loop, so at most you have one consumer and one producer loop doing all the work.

Consider the following approach instead:

```
static volatile int buffer_data;      /* A single-character buffer */
static sem_t        buffer_produced;
static sem_t        buffer_consumed;

void *consumer(void *unused) {
    while (1) {

        /* Wait for data in the buffer. */
        sem_wait(&buffer_produced);

        /* sleep(1); */

        /* End of data? */
        if (buffer_data == EOF) {
            /* If there are other consumers, wake up next one */
            sem_post(&buffer_produced);
            break;
        }

        /* Consume it. */
        fputc(stdout, buffer_data);
        fflush(stdout);

        sem_post(&buffer_consumed);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The consumer waits on the `buffer_produced` semaphore (which should be initialized to zero).  Then, it examines the produced data, `buffer_data`, which is a single character, or `EOF` to indicate no more data.

If there are more than one consumer, we need to post on the `buffer_produced` semaphore, to ensure every consumer sees the `EOF` too.  Then, the thread exits.  (All consumers will exit more or less in a gang, at the same produced `EOF`.)

If the data is not an `EOF`, the consumer prints it to standard output.  Because standard output is buffered by default, we `fflush(stdout)` to ensure the printed character is delivered to the screen (or pipe or file if standard output is redirected to something).

Finally, the consumer posts on the `buffer_consumed` semaphore, to indicate producers that the buffer should now be populated by the next data character.

The commented out `sleep(1);` would delay the printing of each character by one second, so you'd see the characters appear at one second intervals.

The producers that produce a string message could be something like the following:

```
static const char message_str[] = "Hello, world!\n";
static size_t     message_pos = 0;

void *producer(void *) {
    int  c;

    do {

        sem_wait(&buffer_consumed);

        c = message_str[message_pos];
        if (c != '\0') {
            buffer_data = c;
            message_pos++;
        } else {
            buffer_data = EOF;
        }
        sem_post(&buffer_produced);

    } while (c != EOF);

    return NULL;
}
```

The producer waits on `buffer_consumed` semaphore, which should be initialized to 1.  Essentially, when `buffer_consumed == 1`, it means the buffer is empty.

It then examines the next character of the string to be produced.  If it is end-of-string, we convert it to `EOF`. (Why? No reason, really; except that this way you can easily modify a producer to produce binary data including embedded nul bytes.)

The producer sets the `buffer_data` to the character or `EOF`, and posts on the `buffer_produced` semaphore, so that a consumer can consume it.

If it was `EOF`, the producer is done, and can exit.

Note that when `message_pos` points to the end-of-string nul character, `'\0'`, we do not increment it.  This is so that if you have multiple producers, they too see the end-of-string nul character (producing an "another" `EOF`), and exit.

If there are `N` more producers than consumers, then after the last consumer returns, the main thread needs to post `N` times on the `buffer_consumed` semaphore to have all the producers wake up and exit.  (So, if you have 1 consumer and 4 producers, you need to `sem_post(&buffer_consumed)` 3 times.)

If you examine the flow of the program, you'll see that each semaphore never gets posted more than once, before it is waited on, except at the very end when the threads are exiting without producing/consuming any data.